# How can I avoid users entering php code into my form

Tags: php, encoding, sql-injection

How can I stop users entering `<?php ?>` into my forms.

I am using urlencode() and then using urldecode() when echoing data onto my page what is the best thing to do??

**UPDATE:**

I am writing to the database with the text urlencoded:

```
htmlentities (urlencode($_POST['postmessage']));
```

I am using:

```
<?php echo htmlentities (urldecode($row['content'])) ?>
```

to echo the saved data. Is that enough??

Comment: If you `echo()` something like `<?php ..code.. ?>`, that wouldn't be run as PHP code, but it would be sent directly to the browser, which would simply ignore it. Therefore users can enter PHP code into your forms without doing any harm, unless of course you use `eval()` or `include()`/`require()` with user input, which you shouldn't do anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for that:

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in    PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious    code (better known as
>   XSS) with a thoroughly audited,
>   secure yet permissive whitelist,   it
>   will also make sure your documents are
>   standards compliant, something only
>   achievable with a    comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get rid of all the characters that don't belong in a URL

```
$var = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

Then you can check that it is a valid URL

```
$var = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
if($var == false)
    die("Bad URL");
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you doing with the code? execute it?
when you echo the php code theres no need to worry server side... you rather want to do html_entity_encode to keep your website from beeing messed up or beeing injected by iframes/javascripts by user posts